# how to do JSON parsing in Registration Page

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am facing trouble in JSON parsing. When I have completed the code and run this, then the problem is occurred:

> no known class method for selector 'show alert:with message'.

Following is my code:

```
if (!isValid) {
    [AppDelegate showAlert:@"Alert!" withMessage:strMessage];
}
return isValid;



}

-(void)registerUser{
[Loading startLoading:YES];
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"URL=//%@",Access_Token];
//username, password, name, email, country
NSString *parameter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"firstname=%@&lastname=%@email=%@&username=%@&password=%@&confirmpassword=@",fnameField.text,lnameField.text,eamilField.text,unameField.text,passField.text,cpassField];
NSConnection *conn = [[NSConnection alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
[conn sendRequest:urlString withParaMeter:parameter withMethod:@"POST" withTag:1];
[conn startAsynchronousRequest];


}



-(void)NSConnection:(NSConnection*)conn didFailWithError:(NSError*)error withTag:(int)tag{
NSLog(@"error is:- %@",[error description]);



}





-(void)NSConnection:(NSConnection*)request didSuccessWithItems:(NSDictionary*)dicData withData:(NSData*)data withTag:(int)tag{
NSLog(@"all data is:- %@",dicData);
int returnCode = [[dicData valueForKeyPath:@"process.returncode"] intValue];
NSString *strMessage = @"";
returnCode = 0;


switch (returnCode) {
    case 0:
        break;
    case 1:
        strMessage = @"User not logged in/process Id not available.";
        break;
    case 2:
        strMessage = @"Invalid parameters passed.";
        break;
    case 3:
        strMessage = @"Access token doesn't exist.";
        break;
    default:
        strMessage = @"User name allready exist.";

        break;
}
[AppDelegate showAlert:@"Alert!" withMessage:strMessage];
[Loading stopLoading];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you are trying to call that method on object AppDelegate

However the AppDelegate class does not implement it.

Hence the error. Make sure it is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Two chances for this issue

1. You are not declared the `showAlert: withMessage:` method signature in your `@interface`
2. You may be declared it as a instance method, you are calling it using the Class name.

**Fixes:**

1. Declare the method signature in your `@interface`
2. Either define your method as Class method else call it using your app delegate's instance